APEX API Call after another API Call - uncommitted work pending
I am trying to create a trigger that will fetch info from DB and populate fields in SF. Problem is that I need to fetch first basic info and then with this info do another API call to fetch the rest.
I have created a trigger:
trigger GPTrigger on Case (before update) {
   
    if (GPTriggerControl.isTriggerAlreadyExecuted) {
        return; // Exit if the trigger has already run in this context
    }

    GPTriggerControl.isTriggerAlreadyExecuted = true;

    for (Case caseRecord : Trigger.new) {
        Case oldCaseRecord = Trigger.oldMap.get(caseRecord.Id);
        if (caseRecord.RFI_Order_ID__c != null && 
            caseRecord.RFI_Order_ID__c != oldCaseRecord.RFI_Order_ID__c) {
            System.debug('Processing Case ID: ' + caseRecord.Id + ', Order_Id__c: ' + caseRecord.RFI_Order_ID__c);
            System.debug('Enqueuing GPQueueable for Order ID: ' + caseRecord.RFI_Order_ID__c);
            System.enqueueJob(new GPQueueable(caseRecord.RFI_Order_ID__c, caseRecord.Id));
        } else if (caseRecord.RFI_Order_ID__c == null) {
            System.debug('Order_Id__c is null for Case ID: ' + caseRecord.Id);
        } else {
            System.debug('No change in Order_Id__c for Case ID: ' + caseRecord.Id);
        }
    }
}

then I have Queueable class:
public class GPQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private String orderId;
    private Id caseId;

    public GPQueueable(String orderId, Id caseId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.caseId = caseId;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        System.debug('Executing GPQueueable for Order ID: ' + orderId + ', Case ID: ' + caseId);
        
        // Fetch order details
        Map<String, Object> orderDetails = GPService.getOrderDetails(orderId, caseId);
        
        // After fetching the order details, fetch the rest.
        if (orderDetails != null) {
            // Extract order ID and order type
            String orderIdFetched = (String) orderDetails.get('orderid');
            String orderTypeFetched = (String) orderDetails.get('initordertype');

            System.debug('Getting BankAndStatus for orderId:' + orderIdFetched + ' and orderType:' + orderTypeFetched);
            GPService.getBankAndStatus(orderIdFetched, caseId, orderTypeFetched);
        }
    }
}

And then class with methods:
public class GPService {
    
    // Reusable method for making HTTP callouts
    private static HttpResponse makeHttpCallout(String endpoint, String requestBody) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(requestBody);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');  // Set appropriate headers if needed

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        return res;
    }

    // Reusable method to parse and extract data from the API response
    private static Map<String, Object> parseApiResponse(HttpResponse res) {
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Map<String, Object> responseData = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
            if (responseData.containsKey('result')) {
                Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) responseData.get('result');
                List<Object> data = (List<Object>) result.get('data');
                if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                    return (Map<String, Object>) data[0];
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.debug('Error: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' - ' + res.getBody());
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Method to update Case record fields based on the provided field map
    private static void updateCaseFields(Id caseId, Map<String, Object> fieldValues) {
        if (fieldValues != null) {
            Case caseToUpdate = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId LIMIT 1];
            
            // Dynamically set Case fields based on the provided map
            for (String fieldName : fieldValues.keySet()) {
                caseToUpdate.put(fieldName, fieldValues.get(fieldName));
            }
            
            System.debug('Updating Case ID: ' + caseId + ' with fields: ' + fieldValues);
            update caseToUpdate;
        } else {
            System.debug('No data found in the API response');
        }
    }

    // Method to fetch order details
    public static Map<String, Object> getOrderDetails(String orderId, Id caseId) {
        try {
            String requestBody = 'xxx';
            System.debug('Making API call for Order ID: ' + orderId);
            HttpResponse res = makeHttpCallout('xxx', requestBody);
            System.debug('API Response Status Code: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' - ' + res.getBody());

            Map<String, Object> order = parseApiResponse(res);
            if (order != null) {
                Map<String, Object> fieldValues = new Map<String, Object>();
                fieldValues.put('RFI_Order_Type__c', order.get('initordertype'));

                updateCaseFields(caseId, fieldValues);
                
                System.debug('Returning: ' + order);
                return order; // Return the populated fieldValues map
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error during API callout: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null; // Return null if no order was found or an error occurred
    }
    
    public static void getBankWithdrawalDetails(String orderId, Id caseId) {
        try {
            String requestBody = 'xxx';
            System.debug('Making BankAndStatus API call for Order ID: ' + orderId);
            HttpResponse res = makeHttpCallout('xxx', requestBody);
            System.debug('BankAndStatus API Response Status Code: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' - ' + res.getBody());

            Map<String, Object> order = parseApiResponse(res);
            if (order != null) {
                Map<String, Object> fieldValues = new Map<String, Object>();
                fieldValues.put('RFI_Bank__c', order.get('ecosysaccount'));
                fieldValues.put('RFI_Status__c', order.get('bankwithdrawalstatus'));

                updateCaseFields(caseId, fieldValues);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error during BankAndStatus API callout: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public static void getBankAndStatus(String orderId, Id caseId, String orderType) {
        System.debug('Gettting Bank And Status for orderId: ' + orderId + ' and orderType: ' + orderType);

    
                getBankWithdrawalDetails(orderId, caseId);
            
    }
}

But all I get is: BankAndStatus API callout: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
Afaik the changes should be commited in the updateCaseFields method so not sure what is happening.
Any help please?

If you have the record Id, you don't need to query for the record to be able to update it. You can use the SObject constructor to set the Id. Case toUpdate = new Case(Id = 'something'); toUpdate.Subject = 'Other'; update toUpdate; works just fine.

In general, if you have a business requirement wherein callout -> do DML -> do another callout -> do DML where the second callout depends on the first record being DML'd, then you'll need chained queueables - one to do callout 1 + DML, then another to do callout 2 + DML

Changes due to DML aren't "committed" until the end of the entire transaction, so you need to complete all of your callouts before performing any DML (and stuff like enqueuing a queueable does also cause this error because they implicitly insert into AsyncApexJob).
You'll need to re-arrange your code accordingly so that you don't call updateCaseFields() in getOrderDetails(), at the very least.
